# SSL Wild Card issue

Tags: asp.net, ssl, iis-7.5

We have used wild card subdomain to our web app running iis.it is working fine.Now we purchases ssl and implemented , it is working for https://www.xyz.domain.com or  https://www.domain.com but did not work on https://domain.com.

Please help|||||

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your SSL certificate was issued for www.domain.com. Typically, when you purchase an SSL certificate that is "wild card", the CA puts two DNS names in the subject alternative name of the certificate. For you, it is probably `www.domain.com` and `*.www.domain.com`. It is unlikely that the certificate is issued for `domain.com` because it would not be valid for `www.xyz.domain.com` since wildcards only go one sub domain deep.

You need to work with your CA on getting the right kind of certificate. You need a certificate that is valid for `domain.com`, `www.domain.com`, and `*.www.domain.com`. There is nothing you can do to work around this other than get a new certificate with the correct SAN.

Comment: my certificate is *.domain.com only. do i need to add more and is it chargeable again

Comment: @rajeev.harbola You still need a new SSL certificate, one that includes the "root" domain then. `*.domain.com` is not valid for "domain.com", only subdomains.